# How do I change issuetype in Jira using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, jira

Using the PowerShell module JiraPS from Atlassian, I can work with all my Jira-issues using PowerShell.

However, I'm looking for a way to change the IssueType of an existing issue.
I'm required to specify an issue type when creating a new issue.

```
New-JiraIssue -Project PROJ1 -Summary 'New Issue' -IssueType 'Task'
```

But the argument `-Issuetype` is missing from `Set-JiraIssue`, so I assume I need to use the `-Fields` argument. But I can't find any examples about how to use it in the documentation.

I would also need to take into account if it's a subtask or not.